# Getting values using python-pandas groupby-aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Date       Forward_Date    A    B    C    D   Amount
    2010-01-01  2010-02-01     a    a    a    a     20
    2010-01-01  2010-03-01     b    b    b    b     10
    2010-01-01  2010-04-01     c    c    c    c      5
    2010-01-02  2010-02-01     d    d    d    d     15
    2010-01-02  2010-03-01     e    f    e    e     30
    2010-01-02  2010-04-01     f    f    f    f     70
```

What I would like to get is something like this:

```
    Date       Forward_Date    A    B    C    D   Amount
    2010-01-01  2010-02-01     a    a    a    a     20
    2010-01-02  2010-04-01     f    f    f    f     70
```

So I want to select those unique entries from Date column where the amount is maximum and then populate the other cells with corresponding data.

I tried `df.groupby(df['Date']).agg({'Amount':'max'}).reset_index()` that gets me this:

```
    Date          Amount
    2010-01-01      20
    2010-01-02      70
```

But I can't get the other columns to get populated using the intersection of these two column values.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Date` column as the index, perform a groupby on the `Amount` column, get a boolean for rows in the original dataframe that are equal to the groupby result and index with `loc` :

```
df = df.set_index("Date")

df.loc[lambda x: x.Amount.eq(df.groupby("Date").Amount.max())]

        Forward_Date    A   B   C   D   Amount
Date                        
2010-01-01  2010-02-01  a   a   a   a   20
2010-01-02  2010-04-01  f   f   f   f   70
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be merge(inner join) your output on date and amount back to the input table and get the required columns ex:

```
pd.merge(df,df.groupby(df['Date']).agg({'Amount':'max'}).reset_index(),on=['Date','Amount'])
```

This will give you the whole row by date containing max amount

Answer (score 0):

So after bashing my head around a few posts ( and not bothering to look at my own post XD), I came across the following solution which works as well:

`df.sort_values(by = ['Amount'], ascending = False).drop_duplicates(subset = 'Date').sort_values(by = ['Date'])`

Note that the solutions given by Manish and Sammy work perfectly as well and result in the same dataframe. Cheers!